# Display json data in fusion charts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, fusioncharts

I want to show dynamic data in fusion charts which is coming from API. I'm using fusion charts to show value in angular chart. How to assign JSON data to value field of chart property. i have decoded the dataframe and getting the value like "24" in the console log . which i need to show in fusion chart angular chart.

*sample data*

```
    {"id":4753666,"timestamp":"2017-02-17","dataFrame":"TEVOOjbb==","fcnt":243,"port":2,"rssi":-113,"snr":-4.19,"sf_used":9,"decrypted":true}
```

code

```
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://static.fusioncharts.com/code/latest/fusioncharts.js?cacheBust=8232"></script>
        <script src="http://fusioncharts.github.io/angular-fusioncharts/demos/js/angular-fusioncharts.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://static.fusioncharts.com/code/latest/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fint.js?cacheBust=8232"></script>

        <script>
            var app = angular.module('myApp', ["ng-fusioncharts"])
            app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $http) {
                $http.get('https://example.com', {
                    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic passwordbase64==' }
                })
                .then(function (response) {
                     $scope.names = response.data;
               $scope.decodedFrame = atob($scope.names.dataFrame);
               $scope.decodedFrameNew = $scope.decodedFrame.substring(4);
               $scope.distanceinFeet = $scope.decodedFrameNew * 11.5*2;
               $scope.Value = $scope.distanceinFeet / 148;
               $scope.ValueinCm = $scope.Value.toFixed(2);
               console.log($scope.ValueinCm )
                });
        });

             var myData = {
            "chart": {
                "caption": "Bin 1",
                "lowerLimit": "0",
                "upperLimit": "14",
                "showValue": "1",
                "valueBelowPivot": "1",
                "theme": "fint"
            },
            "colorRange": {
                "color": [{
                    "minValue": "0",
                    "maxValue": "5",
                    "code": "#e44a00"
                }, {
                    "minValue": "5",
                    "maxValue": "10",
                    "code": "#f8bd19"
                }, {
                    "minValue": "10",
                    "maxValue": "14",
                    "code": "#6baa01"
                }]
            },
            "dials": {
                "dial": [{
                    "value": "34"
                }]
            }
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        <fusioncharts id="chartContainer1" width="450" height="400" type="angulargauge" dataSource={{decodedFrame}}></fusioncharts>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can following link to store JSON:[link](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/gauge-and-widgets-guide/angular-gauge/simple-gauge-example.html)

And link for program : [link](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/api/fusioncharts.html)

And you can follow below code which is executing successfully.

```
  <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://static.fusioncharts.com/code/latest/fusioncharts.js?cacheBust=8232"></script>
            <script src="http://fusioncharts.github.io/angular-fusioncharts/demos/js/angular-fusioncharts.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://static.fusioncharts.com/code/latest/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fint.js?cacheBust=8232"></script>

            <script>
                var app = angular.module('myApp', ["ng-fusioncharts"])
                app.controller('MyController', function($scope, $http) {
                            /*$http.get('https://example.com', {
                                headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic passwordbase64==' }
                            })
                            .then(function (response) {
                                $scope.names = response.data;
                                $scope.decodedFrame = atob($scope.names.dataFrame);*/

                                //Here you can plot you response json in fusioncharts

                                var myChart = new FusionCharts({
                                        type: 'angulargauge',
                                        renderAt: 'chart-container',

                                        dataFormat: 'json',
                                        dataSource: {
                                                "chart": {
                                                    "caption": "Customer Satisfaction Score",
                                                    "subcaption": "Last week",
                                                    "lowerLimit": "0",
                                                    "upperLimit": "100",
                                                    "lowerLimitDisplay": "Bad",
                                                    "upperLimitDisplay": "Good",
                                                    "showValue": "1",
                                                    "valueBelowPivot": "1",
                                                    "theme": "fint"
                                                },
                                                "colorRange": {
                                                    "color": [{
                                                        "minValue": "0",
                                                        "maxValue": "50",
                                                        "code": "#e44a00"
                                                    }, {
                                                        "minValue": "50",
                                                        "maxValue": "75",
                                                        "code": "#f8bd19"
                                                    }, {
                                                        "minValue": "75",
                                                        "maxValue": "100",
                                                        "code": "#6baa01"
                                                    }]
                                                },
                                                "dials": {
                                                    "dial": [{
                                                        "value": "67"
                                                    }]
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });

                                    // Render the chart.
                                    myChart.render();
                            //});
                            });

                        //      var myData = {
                        //     "chart": {
                        //         "caption": "Bin 1",
                        //         "lowerLimit": "0",
                        //         "upperLimit": "14",
                        //         "showValue": "1",
                        //         "valueBelowPivot": "1",
                        //         "theme": "fint"
                        //     },
                    //     chart: {
                    //         caption: "Harry's SuperMart",
                    //         subCaption: "Top 5 stores in last month by revenue",
                    //     },
                    //     data:[{
                    //         label: "Bakersfield Central",
                    //         value: "880000"
                    //     },
                    //     {
                    //         label: "Garden Groove harbour",
                    //         value: "730000"
                    //     },
                    //     {
                    //         label: "Los Angeles Topanga",
                    //         value: "590000"
                    //     },
                    //     {
                    //         label: "Compton-Rancho Dom",
                    //         value: "520000"
                    //     },
                    //     {
                    //         label: "Daly City Serramonte",
                    //         value: "330000"
                    //     }]
                    // }
                        //     "colorRange": {
                        //         "color": [{
                        //             "minValue": "0",
                        //             "maxValue": "5",
                        //             "code": "#e44a00"
                        //         }, {
                        //             "minValue": "5",
                        //             "maxValue": "10",
                        //             "code": "#f8bd19"
                        //         }, {
                        //             "minValue": "10",
                        //             "maxValue": "14",
                        //             "code": "#6baa01"
                        //         }]
                        //     },
                        //     "dials": {
                        //         "dial": [{
                        //             "value": "34"
                        //         }]
                        //     }
                        // };
            </script>
        </head>
        <body ng-app="myApp">
            <div ng-controller="MyController">
                <div id="chart-container">FusionCharts will load here...</div>
                <!-- <fusioncharts id="chartContainer1" width="450" height="400" type="angulargauge" dataSource="myData"></fusioncharts> -->
            </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: i need dynamic data , not static data that 67 which u have fixed.

Comment: if you give me your response sample,Then i will give you hint how to do for dynamic rendering..

Answer (score -2):

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
   <%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/fusioncharts@3.12.0/fusi`enter code here`oncharts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" enter code heresrc="https://unpkg.com/fusioncharts@3.12.0/fusioncharts.charts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/fusioncharts@3.12.0/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fint.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/fusioncharts/fusioncharts-jquery-plugin/feature/node-commonjs-support/package/fusioncharts-jquery-plugin.js"></script>

 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chart-container">FusionCharts will render here...</div>
    <div id="chart-container2">FusionCharts will render here</div>
     <div id="chart-container3" style="margin-left: 54%;margin-top: -56%;">FusionCharts will render here</div>
     <div id="chart-container4" style="margin-left: 54%;">FusionCharts will render here``


     </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery('document').ready(function () {
            $("#chart-container").insertFusionCharts({
                type: "column2d",
                width: "500",
                height: "300",
                dataFormat: "json",
                dataSource: {
                    "chart": {
                        "caption": "Course Admission",
                        "xAxisName": "Course Name",
                        "yAxisName": "NO Of Admission",
                        "numberPrefix": " ",
                        "theme": "fint"
                    },
                    "data": [{
                        "label": ""fgf",
                        "value": "10"
                    },  {
                        "label": "gfdfg",
                        "value": "10"
                    }]
                }
            });
        });     


        jQuery('document').ready(function () {


              $("#chart-container2").insertFusionCharts({
                type: 'doughnut2d',
                renderAt: 'chart-container2',
                width: '500',
                height: '300',
                dataFormat: 'json',
                dataSource: {
                    "chart": {
                        "caption": "cvbcvb",
                        "subCaption": "bcvb",
                        "numberPrefix": " ",
                        "paletteColors": "#0075c2,#1aaf5d,#f2c500,#f45b00,#8e0000",
                        "bgColor": "#ffffff",
                        "showBorder": "0",
                        "use3DLighting": "0",
                        "showShadow": "0",
                        "enableSmartLabels": "0",
                        "startingAngle": "310",
                        "showLabels": "0",
                        "showPercentValues": "1",
                        "showLegend": "1",
                        "legendShadow": "0",
                        "legendBorderAlpha": "0",
                        "defaultCenterLabel": "Total cbvc: 500",
                        "centerLabel": "Revenue from $label: $value",
                        "centerLabelBold": "1",
                        "showTooltip": "0",
                        "decimals": "0",
                        "captionFontSize": "14",
                        "subcaptionFontSize": "14",
                        "subcaptionFontBold": "0"
                    },
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "label": "cvbcv",
                            "value": "55"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "label": "cvbc",
                            "value": "22"
                        }

                    ]
                }
            });
        });


        jQuery('document').ready(function () {
            $("#chart-container3").insertFusionCharts({
                type: 'area2d',
                renderAt: 'chart-container3',
                width: '500',
                height: '300',
                dataFormat: 'json',
                dataSource: {
                    "chart": {
                        "caption": "fghfghProcess",
                        "subCaption": "week",
                        "xAxisName": "Day",
                        "yAxisName": " ",
                        "numberPrefix": " ",
                        "paletteColors": "#0075c2",
                        "bgColor": "#ffffff",
                        "showBorder": "0",
                        "showCanvasBorder": "0",
                        "plotBorderAlpha": "10",
                        "usePlotGradientColor": "0",
                        "plotFillAlpha": "50",
                        "showXAxisLine": "1",
                        "axisLineAlpha": "25",
                        "divLineAlpha": "10",
                        "showValues": "1",
                        "showAlternateHGridColor": "0",
                        "captionFontSize": "14",
                        "subcaptionFontSize": "14",
                        "subcaptionFontBold": "0",
                        "toolTipColor": "#ffffff",
                        "toolTipBorderThickness": "0",
                        "toolTipBgColor": "#000000",
                        "toolTipBgAlpha": "80",
                        "toolTipBorderRadius": "2",
                        "toolTipPadding": "5"
                    },

                    "data": [
                        {
                            "label": "Mon",
                            "value": "41"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "label": "Tue",
                            "value": "46"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "label": "Wed",
                            "value": "55"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "label": "Thu",
                            "value": "4"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "label": "Fri",
                            "value": "5"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "label": "Sat",
                            "value": "58"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "label": "Sun",
                            "value": "6"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            })

        });

     /*    jQuery('document').ready(function () {
              $("#chart-container4").insertFusionCharts({
                 */

                 jQuery('document').ready(function () {
                     $("#chart-container4").insertFusionCharts({
                            type: 'bar2d',
                            renderAt: 'chart-container4',
                            width: '500',
                            height: '300',
                            dataFormat: 'json',
                            dataSource: {
                                "chart": {
                                    "caption": "gfhfgResults",
                                    "subCaption": "2017",
                                    "yAxisName": "Status",
                                    "paletteColors": "#0075c2",
                                    "bgColor": "#ffffff",
                                    "showBorder": "0",
                                    "showCanvasBorder": "0",
                                    "usePlotGradientColor": "0",
                                    "plotBorderAlpha": "10",
                                    "placeValuesInside": "1",
                                    "valueFontColor": "#ffffff",
                                    "showAxisLines": "1",
                                    "axisLineAlpha": "25",
                                    "divLineAlpha": "10",
                                    "alignCaptionWithCanvas": "0",
                                    "showAlternateVGridColor": "0",
                                    "captionFontSize": "14",
                                    "subcaptionFontSize": "14",
                                    "subcaptionFontBold": "0",
                                    "toolTipColor": "#ffffff",
                                    "toolTipBorderThickness": "0",
                                    "toolTipBgColor": "#000000",
                                    "toolTipBgAlpha": "80",
                                    "toolTipBorderRadius": "2",
                                    "toolTipPadding": "5"
                                },

                                "data": [
                                    {
                                        "label": "gf1",
                                        "value": "88"
                                    }, 
                                    {
                                        "label": "gfhf 2",
                                        "value": "73"
                                    }, 
                                    {
                                        "label": "gfhf 3",
                                        "value": "5"
                                    }, 
                                    {
                                        "label": "gfhh 4",
                                        "value": "52"
                                    }, 
                                    {
                                        "label": "gfh5",
                                        "value": "33"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        })
                        .render();
                    });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't just blurt out code! Adding some text to explain how this code answers the question will help to improve the long-term value of the answer and help to prevent it from being deleted during review.